# CKEditor not displaying Icons in IE 10, but ok in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, ckeditor

When I first upgraded to CKEditor 4.1.2, IE 10 did not work when I hosted on my local machine, but in Chrome. I only got  a black rectangle where CKEditor was supposed to be. After lots of trial I found out that I can make also IE 10 work by using this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But when I uploaded the ASP.NET website to the hoster, only Chrome worked properly. The CKEditor functionality worked in IE 10, but no icons where displayed. I could not see the buttons, but click on them and they worked. When I analised what the IE is downloading, I found only this strange case:

From local host (meaning everything works):
    "ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png    GET    200    **image/png    26.30 KB**    0.53 s    background-image    4836    0    281    249    0    1061"

From hosted website (IE not displaying icons):
    "ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png    GET    304    **application/octet-stream    147 B**    < 1 ms    background-image    530    0    0    0    0    1575574"

Any idea what could be the problem ?

I faced this problem for more than 1 week, during which I restarted the browser,  my PC, etc. I also had it today, but when I played with the IE developer tools to investigate the data exchange between browser and server, the problem disappeared after 1 hour, without me changing anything on the server, even not clearing the browser cach.